# For não está dando continue (Firemonkey)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Eu estou literalmente desde ontem olhando para essa parte do código tentando descobrir o porque o `for`não está passando de 0. Já tentei de diversas maneiras, e já confirmei que eu estou adicionando sempre mais um número nele, mas simplesmente ele para no 0.

O que eu quero fazer é o seguinte: Vou adicionar sempre uma sequência de números dentro de um `Tedit` e depois apertar para enviá-los. Só que os números inseridos nunca podem ser menores ou iguais aos números anteriormente enviados.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda? Estou usando `Delphi RIO` e estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para `ANDROID`

Aqui está meu código:

```
procedure TF_dianteira.bt_OKEClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  hora_texto: string;
  funcionou_menor: string;
  funcionou_igual: string;
begin
  funcionou_menor := 'sim';
  funcionou_igual := 'sim';
  ShowMessage('vai ate ' +IntToStr(Emb_Maximo));
  for i := 0 to Emb_Maximo do
  begin
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(i));
    if (StrToInt(txt_embarque_d.Text) < vetor[i]) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Numero: ' +txt_embarque_d.Text);
      ShowMessage('Numero anteriormente digitado: ' + IntToStr(vetor[i]));
      ShowMessage('Não pode haver senhas menores que anteriores');
      funcionou_menor := 'nao';
      txt_embarque_d.Text := '';
      break;
    end
    else
    begin
      funcionou_menor := 'sim';
    end;
    if (StrToInt(txt_embarque_d.Text) = vetor[i]) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Não pode haver senhas iguais à anteriores');
      txt_embarque_d.Text := '';
      funcionou_igual := 'nao';
      break;
    end
    else
    begin
      funcionou_igual := 'sim';
    end;

    if (funcionou_menor = 'sim') then
    begin
      if (funcionou_igual = 'sim') then
      begin
        if i <> 0 then
          SetLength(vetor, Length(vetor));

        vetor[Emb_Maximo] := StrToInt(txt_embarque_d.Text);
        ShowMessage('Vetor adicionado ' +IntToStr(vetor[Emb_Maximo]) );

        //Aqui eu vou criar um arquivo

        txt_embarque_d.Text := '';
        Emb_Maximo := Emb_Maximo + 1;
        break;
      end;
    end;

    continue
  end;    

end;
```

Comment: faz tempo que parei de programar em pascal object, mas se nao me engano voce precisa forcar o incremento da tua variavel "i", algo tipo `... continue; i = i + 1;`, nao lembro mais mas tenta ai

Comment: Eu tentei colocar um `continue` ali no final, da uma olhada pra você ver, mas continua o mesmo problema =\ e `i := i+1;` não funciona porque fala que eu estou definindo valor a uma variável de um `for`

Comment: com que valor começa a var Emb_Maximo ? porque só a está a incrementar em algumas situaçoes... logo se começar a 0, provavelmente so faz 1 ou 2 iteraçoes...

Comment: Começa com 0, mas só aumenta se realmente tiver adicionado algum valor, essa é a intenção sabe? por exemplo, se eu inseri "1", futuramente, se eu inserir "1" não pode dar. mas se eu inserir "2", tem que dar, aí o Emb_Maximo tem que aumentar um valor porque adicionou mais um no vetor

Comment: Está difícil entender seu código. Há variáveis globais, então não dá pra entender o contexto. Mas, tem umas coisinhas:
 if i <> 0 then
          SetLength(vetor, Length(vetor));
Percebe que este código não faz nada?
Emb_maximo := Emb_maximo + 1;
Experimente colocar um ponto de parada nessa linha para ver se passa por ela.
continue
remova essa linha, esse comando só faz sentido se você precisar voltar ao início do looping no meio do processamento, ignorando linhas adicionais. no caso, não há linhas adicionais a serem ignoradas, pois o comando está no fim do looping.

Comment: `if i< > 0 then setLength` é porque eu só quero aumentar o tamanho do vetor depois que o `for` não for mais 0

Comment: antes do for atribua 0 ou o valor de início da sua variável i, e no começo do for da um inc(i) para somar um toda vez que passar pelo for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo, pois o `TO` do `FOR` é avaliado somente a primeira vez, logo se sua variável `Emb_Maximo` começo com zero, mesmo incrementando ela dentro do `FOR`, ela não será reavaliada e seu `FOR` vai ser finalizado.

Pense que a estrutura de repetição `FOR` é principalmente utilizada quando você conhece o começo e o final do loop, como seu loop é dinâmico, pode ser alterado durante a execução, recomada-se você utiliza de um `WHILE`, onde a expressão é sempre reavailiada, tornando-se assim dinâmica.

Veja esse exemplo:

```
program Hello;
var i: integer;
    Emb_Maximo: integer;
begin
  //Começa com ZERO, assim como seu exemplo
  Emb_Maximo := 0;

  for i := 0 to Emb_Maximo do
  begin
    writeln(i);
    //Mesmo aumento o valor dentro do for, ele não será reavaliado
    Emb_Maximo += 2;
  end;

  writeln(''); 
  writeln('--'); 
  writeln('');

  //Começa com DOIS
  Emb_Maximo := 2;

  for i := 0 to Emb_Maximo do
  begin
    writeln(i);
    //Mesmo aumento o valor dentro do for, ele não será reavaliado
    Emb_Maximo += 3;
  end;

  writeln(''); 
  writeln('--'); 
  writeln('');

  //Se o seu for é assim dinâmico, faça com WHILE
  Emb_Maximo := 0;
  i := 0;

  while i <= Emb_Maximo do
  begin
    //Apenas para evitar o loop infinito, poderia ser uma condição, algo solicitado ao usuário
    if i = 0 then
    begin
      Emb_Maximo += 4;
    end;

    //Mesmo começando em ZERO, a expressão é reavaliada, com isso o LOOP é executado conforme a alteração do Emb_Maximo
    writeln(i);
    inc(i);
  end;

end.
```

> Execute online: https://rextester.com/QNBV94804

---

Essa condição do `FOR` é específica da linguagem, algumas reavaliam a condição do `FOR`, como por exemplo javascript:

```js
let Emb_Maximo = 0;

for(let i =0; i <=Emb_Maximo; i++) {
  console.log(i);

  if (Emb_Maximo == 0) {
    Emb_Maximo += 2;
  }
}
```